# IdTCPClient is very slow with large StringStream

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-10.1-berlin, hl7-v2

Recently we added base64 encoded pdf file to an HL7 message as a last OBX segment which added 2.5MB to the message (which was only 2kb). That caused tremendous slowing of TCPClient write speed and takes more than 40 seconds.

```
procedure TfrmHL7.SendComposedHL7Message(HL7Msg: string);
var 
  ms         : TStringStream;
begin
 
  ms := TStringStream.Create(HL7Msg);  
  try
      ms.Position := 0;
//TStopWatch.Start
    HL7DM.IdHL7TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);
//TStopWatch.Stop (result: 41000)
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;

end;
```

I tried to inc the buffer size to 65k but that didn't help.

Other than sending the PDF file with a different protocol, any guide on how to speed up the TCP writestream is highly appreciated.

Comment: `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` simply reads from the `TStream` in `IOHandler.SendBufferSize` chunks (32K by default) and transmits each one as-is. I would expect more of a slowdown from the `TStringStream` constructor, which has to first encode a `String` to a `TBytes` using `TEncoding.GetBytes()`. `TIdIOHandler.Write()` would just be reading and sending those encoded bytes as-is. Are you, by chance, using write-buffering on the `IOHandler`? I would suggest eliminating the string conversion from the equation.

Comment: On the other hand, base64 bloats data by only 4/3 times, so a 2KB file encoded as a base64 string would only be 2.6KB (5.3KB in a Unicode string), certainly not 2.5MB.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Lebeau for this feedback. I will look into that.  The 2.6KB message is without the base64 encoding of the pdf file (which is about 600KB), it is the newly added last line OBX segment.  Thank you! Much appreciated.